# Why is -init an instance method and +initialize a class method?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, initialization, nsobject

In Cocoa, for `NSObject`s, shouldn't both `init` and `initialize` be class methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+initialize` can be overridden (it's optional) to perform class-wide initialization.
`-init` performs initialization of a single instance of a class, though it's often refined by adding arguments in classes derived from NSObject (ex: UIView's `initWithFrame:` method).

Since `-init` initializes a single instance (in particular, it has access to the instance's variables), it can't be a class method.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> The runtime sends initialize to each class in a program just before the class, or any class that inherits from it, is sent its first message from within the program.

This means that the first time you send a message to the class, whether it be `alloc` or some defined class method, `initialize` is called first, once, for the entire run of the application. As opposed to `load`, it is possible to include a class in a project and never hit `initialize`.

`init`, on the other hand, is

> Implemented by subclasses to initialize a new object (the receiver) immediately after memory for it has been allocated.

Meaning, `init` is sheerly used for initializing class *instances*.

Edit --

Following the edited question, `alloc` creates the instance while `init` initializes it, which is why `alloc` is a class method and `init` is an instance method.